# Magento onpage checkout anchors need padding

Tags: magento, sticky, megamenu, anchor-scroll

I have a sticky menu on Magento that sticks to the top of the page when a user scrolls down the page. The issue is that Magento has anchors in the onepage checkout process and the anchors sit behind the sticky menu so you lose the headers and top form field labels etc.

I need to add a padding/margin to the top of the anchors or offset them in JS if possible.

I can add the JS code but it's very long, standard Magento 1.9.2.2 code and can be found here skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js

The demo site is here and if you select checkout as a guest and continue you'll see the issue on desktop http://orbdemo.co.nz/cufflinks/checkout/onepage/

Tried a feww css things and nothing worked have also looked online for a hour and can't see anything to help. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for this problem. Basically created a new class that included the body id and then the nav id so I could override the class for position"relative" and change it to position"static" this caused the sticky menu to be static so the anochor work as expected now. Here's the code I used and added it to the superfish.css file on the theme folder.

.checkout-onepage-index .nav-container.fixed{position:static;  }